# Deploy system Spring boot in tomcat 8 - CentOS 8

Tags: java, linux, spring-boot, centos8

I have a Java 8 system - Spring boot with tomcat 8. The system worked on CentOS 7, but the structure was changed to Azure and needed to install new version.

My system is connected to another SQL Server server

To deploy my system, I get an error:

```
The driver could not estalish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: "Server chose TLSv1, but that protocol version is not enabled or not supoorted by the client."
```

My application.properties:

```
spring.thymeleaf.cache=false

#spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://1.1.1.1:1433;DatabaseName=BD;integratedSecurity=true;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=true;
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://1.1.1.1:1433;DatabaseName=BD
spring.datasource.username=ss
spring.datasource.password=XXXXX
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.jackson.serialization.fail-on-empty-beans=false

server.port=8080

spring.mvc.favicon.enabled=false
server.context-path=/sc
```

What can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: Have you tried adding the following properties: `-Djdk.tls.server.protocols=TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2 -Djdk.tls.client.protocols=TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2`?

Comment: no, i add these properties to the url or application.properties?